# Maxwell Equation: Definition of Invariance

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, inertial-frames, maxwell-equations, covariance

Knowing Lorentz Transformation and knowing the differential formulation of Maxwell Equations:

*Precisely*, what is the meaning of the statement: "Maxwell equation are invariant under Lorentz Transformation"?

What do we mean when we say this?

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to stress the careful language used in the two other answers. Maxwells equation are *not* invariant under Lorentz transformations, they  are *covariant*. That is, they keep their *form* when you change frames.   The LHS and RHS of the equations are *not* "invariant"  because they are components of tensors rather than scalars.

Answer (score 1):

It means that if you take a Lorentz transformation of the coordinates, the induced transformation on the fields gives the fields $\vec{E'}$ and $\vec{B'}$, which also obey the Maxwell equations.

Answer (score 1):

An invariance means that the laws or the mathematical form of the equations don't change on changing reference frame. Lorentz invariance in particular means that the equations don't change when we use Lorentz transformations to switch the reference frame.

The Lorentz force law says that
$$ \mathbf{F}=q(\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{v}×\mathbf{B})$$
And say in another reference frame, which is derived from the Lorentz transformations, the quantities are the primed quantities. Lorentz invariance means the force is given as

$$ \mathbf{F'}=q(\mathbf{E'}+\mathbf{v'}×\mathbf{B'})$$

Answer (score 0):

Maxwell equations are invariant under Lorentz transformations means that:

The Maxwell equations don't change their form if the Lorentz transformations laws are applied properly on the field strengths, their sources (the charge density and current) and the coordinates.
In this context on has to keep in mind that the electric and magnetic field strengths are components of an antisymmetric 4x4 tensor, and the charge density and the current are components of a 4-vector.

Comment: Covariant, not invariant.